# Convert Hex String to unsigned Byte Array in Java

Tags: java, hex

I get hex strings of 14 bytes, e.g. `a55a0b05000000000022366420ec`.
I use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(String s)` to get an array of 14 bytes.
Unfortunately those are unsigend bytes like the last one `0xEC` = 236 for example.

But I would like to compare them to bytes like this:
`if(byteArray[13] == 0xec)`
Since 235 is bigger than a signed byte this if statement would fail.
Any idea how to solve this in java?
Thx!

Comment: Treat it as an unsigned byte and comparison is the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `if(byteArray[13] == (byte)0xec)`

Answer (score 3):

You can promote the byte to integer:

```
if((byteArray[13] & 0xff) == 0xec)
```

Answer (score 0):

since java doesn't support (atleast with primitives) any unsigned data types, you should look at using int as your data type to parse the string..

```
        String str = "a55a0b05000000000022366420ec";
        int[] arrayOfValues = new int[str.length() / 2];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 2) {
            String s = str.substring(i, i + 2);
            arrayOfValues[counter] = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
            counter++;
        }
```

work with the `arrayOfValues`...